# Re: JIRA 4.1.2. What makes this query call?

Tags: jira, postgresql-9.2

We are using an unsupported version of JIRA and Atlassian offers no support to us on the topic even though we have a support license.

There was a patch on our database put out this past week and we saw the number of queries on the system jump from 800k to over 36 million per day. The JIRA system is attempting to delete users from groups. The following is what is captured by our EnterpriseDB logs

`"execute <unnamed>: DELETE FROM public.membershipbase WHERE USER_NAME=$1 AND GROUP_NAME=$2"`

We don't understand why it attempts to do this at all and would greatly appreciate any help with identifying the cause of this. I have checked all of the code that we have, I have checked all functions in the DB, I have looked for stored procedures and have even looked into all the views. I am seeing nothing that makes the above call. If you have any experience with this version of JIRA please provide any suggestions you may have. From what I have read the USERBASE and MEMBERSHIPBASE tables have been removed as of version 5.0 which is why I am asking for those with 4.1.2 knowledge.

Comment: Deploy jira-javamelody to monitor sql queries: https://github.com/javamelody/javamelody/releases Then look for the stack traces at the SQL pane.

Comment: Issue with that. We have a very long and lengthy process of deploying anything to production. In addition, we don't have direct access to the DB Server due to security restrictions so we are only able to request a copy of the log and that can take most of if not the entire day to obtain.

Comment: Well, this sounds cumbersome. The thing that makes me hesitant to help is that JIRA 4.x is so outdated it is not even listed on the EOL page: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/Support/Atlassian+Support+End+of+Life+Policy --> "Atlassian does not provide support for instances on versions that are End of Life." --> That's why they don't help. Also, without monitoring tools you're simply not capable to debug this. I use OEM, jira-javamelody, the logs, and Java Mission Control flight recordings to narrow down on the problematic area.

Comment: A few years back when this project was built, they did some serious modifications to the JIRA source and so all attempts over the past 2 years of upgrading have ended up in failure. We informed the client that building from a new JIRA is the only option as this version is not upgradeable and we cannot get any of the knowledge back from those who have left the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A library package called opensymphony is implemented in this project that creates the query.

Why don't people just learn to write their own SQL. It's cleaner and easier IMO.

Answer (score 0):

The `membershipbase` table, as you pointed out, contains the users which belong to JIRA's internal groups. My best guess is that you might have JIRA set up to use LDAP/AD for authentication (using Crowd?) and that it is trying to sync changes in group memberships into JIRA.

If, for example, JIRA were configured with a too-wide LDAP filter for groups that included mailing lists and so on in a huge company, and another company admin were to delete and/or move a bunch of entries in the LDAP tree outside of the filter, I could see this resulting in a large number of deletes happening in JIRA.

A helpful command to run would be this (which, from your above comments, I guess you will need to request from your dBAs):

```
SELECT GROUP_NAME, count(1) FROM public.membershipbase GROUP BY GROUP_NAME ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

This reports the number of users in each group. Then run the same command again a minute later, and diff the output. That should give you an idea of which group(s) are being modified without necessarily having to install SQL monitoring tools. (You might also want to look at how many groups are in JIRA in total, and verify that it seems like a reasonable number.)

Either way, you can then dig into the actual users being updated/deleted and also start asking around with other sysadmins.

You could also try restarting JIRA to see if the updates go away. If it's a legitimate/intended LDAP sync operation, I imagine that the `DELETEs` would start back up again fairly away.

Edited to add:

Instead of the SQL query, the [Group Browser in the admin UI](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA041/Managing+Groups) will also show you some of the same information, although not it's particularly suited for diffing.

Comment: Scott, thank you for your feedback. We have shutdown JIRA many times, we have deleted all index files and have re-indexed the app after startup but still end up with the same results. As far as I am aware of JIRA does use LDAP to authenticate. I however do not know where or how that works. I'm literally looking in a haystack but don't know what I'm looking for. Is it a needle or is it a piece of hay I need to find. ---- Another kicker... I'm the developer so I'm not allowed onto the production system. Conflict of interest I'm told. Only the SA can & we sit 50 ft from each other.

Comment: That furthers my suspicion of the LDAP sync. Well, how many total groups do you have visible in the group browser? If you dig through the list of individual groups once and note how many members are in each individual group, and then go through the list of groups a few minutes later, do you notice any difference in the member count of any group? And now is the time to submit that SQL query to your dBAs.

Comment: You also mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31384641/jira-4-1-2-is-there-a-different-workflow-that-jira-follows-when-submitting-via) that you recently applied a patch to your dB. Is that timing related to the onset of this problem too?

Comment: I have submitted your question to my SA to look into the Browser groups and he is asking of the DBA to run the sql. Not too optimistic being between a rock and a hard place. Yes the timing of the patch was when the system went haywire. We don't have the option to rollback to previous version as other peoples databases are on the same server. Of course the DB team is saying it's our applications issue and not theirs because the Tomcat Server was restarted and that's when things went haywire.

Comment: Found code in the system that pointed to opensymphony which I was told creates the queries. Once that was identified then I understood what was going on and we could see that a limit was set on the number of users allowed. The number of users increased in the system right when people were taking leave so the issue did not show up until people got back from 4th of July vacation. What a pain to solve things when people like to make things obscure.

Comment: So, what was the actual problem? (Post as an answer to your own question?) I ask primarily because OpenSymphony covers a broad set of code, especially in that version of JIRA, including users, issue workflow, etc.

Comment: The fix was to change the limit of 1000 entries into the cache of users that was coded to 100,000. I say it is a hack fix because we don't understand the intent of what was coded. There are no comments in the code, nor any documentation behind why it was set to such a low number.

Answer (score 0):

The fix was to change the limit of 1000 entries into the cache of users that was coded to 100,000.

I say it is a hack fix because we don't understand the intent of what was coded. There are no comments in the code, nor any documentation behind why it was set to such a low number.

> Updated: 9/17/2015 After speaking with a trainer for Jira 6.x they
>   said that this issue was not Jira based. Someone had *modified the
>   source code*. Jira 4.x has no such limiter of 1000 for
>   caching.