# JIRA 4.1.2: Is there a different workflow that Jira follows when submitting via web services?

Tags: jira

Recently a patch was put into production to upgrade our Postgres DB.

Since then, our users are not able to use the GUI to submit tickets, but our users are able to use the Web Services to submit tickets.

How is this possible that one will work over the other if they are both utilizing the same defined workflows in JIRA?

Please provide some insight into under the hood operations of JIRA. Already put a ticket into Atlassian and was shut down by the help there since the version we have has reached End-of-life.

Comment: Can you be more precise regarding "our users are not able to use the GUI to submit tickets"?

Comment: When the user tries to load the form the page never loads and the system times out. There is nothing in any of our server logs and Data Power has one entry stating something along the line of No Header Response received. The user can login and view some of the ares but on editing, creating cloning tickets the system just hangs and NOTHING is logged to tell us why. Again... No code has been modified in over 2 months on production and this just started to happen on the 1st of July.

Comment: Can you rollback the dB patch?

Comment: You can try taking some thread dumps (with jstack) to see if you can isolate where JIRA is hanging (try taking a few dumps and riffing them, with an emphasis on threads that are running, to see if that gives any clues. Alas, since you have mentioned that you have modified the JIRA source code, you might have to directly troubleshoot it yourself. If you figure out where it's getting stuck but don't know why, you can also download a copy of the source code for JIRA and attach a debugger to the Java process so you can figure out exactly what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Scott Dudley
Two parts.

1. Though we thought everything goes through the same path pretty much in JIRA when the users submit data via web services logs revealed that we were dead wrong.
2. The issue that caused the users to not be able to submit data through the GUI was due to the fact that there was some old code written to manage a cache of Users. It had a limit set that was less than the actual number of users so because of how things were coded the system ended up in a nearly infinite loop trying to add all of the users but never able to load them all because the cache would drop users when it was reached but still try and load who was missing from the cache.

Appreciate the suggestions on this and thank you.